# What are the minimum spices I can use to remove meaty smell?

Tags: meat, smell

I cannot eat rare meat. So, I need to cook it. Generally, in my country, we use garlic, ginger, turmeric, cinnamon, cardamom, cloves, oil, and salt to cook meats. But, I am just wondering what if I use only oil, salt, garlic and ginger to cook meat.

What are the minimum spices I can use to remove meaty smell?
Should those spices be different in case of chicken, lamb, and beef?

I guess they are ginger and garlic.

Any other idea?

Comment: You say "meaty smell" in the title and "raw smell" in the body of the question. Which is it? What are you actually trying to achieve? Masking rawness in chicken doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain what you have in mind? For me meaty smell in meat is a desired point. Is your meat smelling bad? Do you want meat to don't smell and taste like meat?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, I cannot eat rare meat. So, I need to cook it. Generally, in my country, we use garlic, ginger, turmeric, cinnamon, cardamom, cloves, oil, and salt to cook meats. But, I am just wondering what if I use only oil, salt, garlic and ginger to cook meat.

Comment: It is totally unclear just what you want to accomplish. While you can 'mask'/hide a smell with another, actually removing it with spices isn't practical. Are you aiming to do this in the raw state, while it is cooking or in the finished state?

Comment: Why not eat something else? I don't understand this question.

Comment: If you want to know "what if" regarding something as subjective as taste, why don't you try yourself?

Comment: Just garlic and/or ginger is enough from my personal experience.

Comment: @xuq01, what is your background, Chinese?

Comment: Yes. That's often how we cook meat where I am from.

Comment: It depends on the meat, for a steak for example. I cook it in butter and just add salt and pepper and done...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand what you're asking for.

First, Oil is a method of transportation for flavour. If you infuse oil with herbs it will taste like those herbs and everything that is coated by this oil will smell like them. That's why we use flavour infused oils for cooking. Or why recipes call for frying garlic or onions in oil before you throw in your meat.

So it's not about what you use but in what order. If you cook garlic and ginger first they will release the smell and the oil will be infused with it. Then when you cook the meat will be instantly coated and won't release it's own smell (or it will be masked). Bonus to this is that you will sear the meat immediately (because the oil is hot) so the outside of meat will trap everything inside the chunk.

Any spice or herb will help you to mask meat smell. There are some herbs that go better with different meat. For me for example for chicken it's curry, ginger, coriander. For lamb it's cumin, nutmeg, paprika (sweet and hot). Beef goes well with black pepper and salt.

Now a piece of advice. If you want to minimize the chances of meat smell - marinade meats. Make or buy some flavour infused oils and use them in marinades with some extra spices and herbs (I have basic oils that I mix with fresh herbs for marinade) and then transfer that meat to a preheated pan with a spoonful of oil.